# In android coding of share button got null pointer exception on this line mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

Tags: android, share-button

[Logcat Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iFjo.png)  In android coding of share button got `NullPointerException` on this line `mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());`
Can  anyone solve this error?

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    // Now get the ShareActionProvider from the item
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);

    /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
   // mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share).getActionProvider();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

/** Returns a share intent */
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Extra Text");
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: post logcat error here.

Comment: Open  this  link  for   logcat :http://i.stack.imgur.com/6iFjo.png

Comment: which code in `MainActivity.java line 60`

Comment: mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

Comment: Can you post your menu, specifically the item represented by `R.id.menu_item_share`? It must be an instance of `SupportMenuItem` else the `getActionProvider()` will return `null`.

Comment: @Angel I mention reason and also provide answer.

Comment: ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass=
            "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

</menu>

Comment: @Angel see my answer do it slowly so you do not make any mistake and also I comment all the part so you can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UpDate :

import this

```
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

declare it global

```
 private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate menu resource file.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider  = (ShareActionProvider)shareItem..getActionProvider();

       
       setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());    


          // Return true to display menu
        return true;

    }

 // Call to update the share intent    
 private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
      if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
           mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
      }
 }

/** Returns a share intent */
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Extra Text");
    return shareIntent;
}
```

Comment: not working;  gives  an   error of inconvertible  type

Comment: ur   ans  is   right ,  but   give the  exception that  it is   not  supported and  use   MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()

Comment: @Angel what exception is occure.

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:

Comment: @Angel see my answer do it slowly so you do not make any mistake and also I comment all the part so you can understand.

Comment: again same  exception